# Is it possible to use add_filter in an included file in the child theme's functions.php?

Tags: functions, filters, hooks, child-theme

I am trying something basic but I can't seem to figure it out or I am not even sure if it is possible to be done in a child theme.

What is am trying is to organize the the codes in the functions.php file in the child theme by creating a separate directory for include files and have all the files in there.

Basically, here is the code in my **functions.php** file:

```
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/myfile.php');
```

And then **myfile.php** got this code:

```
function myfunction( $src ) {

}
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'myfunction');
```

But then I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function add_filter()
```

So now I am wondering if there is a way for me to do what I am trying to achieve in a child theme. I have tried this approach in a parent theme and it seemed to work fine.

Thanks in advance for explanation and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is possible.

When including php files, use `get_stylesheet_directory()` in child themes and `get_template_directory()` in parent themes.

E.g.
`require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/myfile.php');`

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` and `get_template_directory_uri()` will return URLs. Those functions are useful when enqueuing public assets such as stylesheets and JavaScript.

Also, setting `allow_url_include` to `Off` in your php.ini will provide better error reporting in these situations ([source](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/178984/2807)).

Comment: Yes, what you suggested is what I have in my code, see codes in the post above. My problem is that in my file.php inside the inc directory, when I use the add_filter code, it throws the error that add_filter is an undefined function.

Comment: No, our code is not the same! Mine works :) Take a closer look please. You are using [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) and I'm using [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory). Those are two different functions. [Here's a great supplement](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/11/17/how-to-load-files-within-wordpress-themes) to the Codex on loading files within WordPress.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Thanks a lot! My code works now. Thanks for the reference links as well. They helped a lot! :)

Comment: No worries! Glad it's working now.